# Meaning of "boning"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, deverbal-adjectives

Here are a few words from Jeffrey Bernard; they can be read in the [*Spectator*](http://archive.spectator.co.uk/article/11th-june-1988/41/jeffrey-bernard).

> *But, having said that vodka is my favourite drink, I suppose whisky is the best all-rounder in the world. It does make people go mad though. When I was banged up in the bin in 1972 for three months 90 per cent of the inmates were whisky drinkers. Most of them were covered with scars as the result of accidents or fights.*
>
> *I find beer boning and a soporific and I also don't have the cubic capacity for it any more. I love good claret and hate wine without food. People who drink quantities of dry white wine without eating usually smell like drains. But neither good wine nor the best beer give me a cerebral kick, confidence or feelings of safety and secur- ity.*

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boning) gives  a practical definition that could lead to a figurative meaning.

> **bone** *verb*
> to take the bones out of something:
> The chef bones the fish before grilling it.

Perhaps "boning" might mean "making feel physically flabby all over, maybe weak", but nothing is less certain.

The SOED is  better in the way of suggesting a figuartive meaning but is far from contributing to a resolution.

> **bone**
> **1** *v.t* Remove the bones from (meat, fish, etc.). L15.
> **2** *v.t.* Treat or equip with bone, *esp.* as stiffening or strengthening. L17.
> **3** *v.i.* Apply oneself diligently; study intensively. Usu. foll. by *up*, study hurriedly. (Foll. by *on* the object of study etc.). *slang* (orig. *US*). M19.
> **4** *v.i.* Point a bone at (a person) as part of an Australian Aboriginal ritual intended to bring about death or sickness. E20.

Besides the possibility that "1" offers (considered above), there is an unclear choice to be made between senses "2" and "3" so as to converge towards a possible figurative meaning.

Would the meaning be "stiffening  behaviour,  reactions or some mental feature of the individual" (2) or would it be "having an effect that drives to become busy, reflective or something like that" (3)? If it is either one of these two, I still can't decide which one rather than the other does apply.

Could someone clarify the meaning of this participial adjective?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an OCR transcription error

Comment: Zooming in on the printed text confirms the word is actually "boring," which fits the context much better. Optical character recognition can easily confuse "r" and "n."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply a typo for "boring." [*Soporific*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/soporific) means sleep-inducing, so the context fits, and makes a much simpler meaning than any far-fetched obscure meaning of "bone." If optical character recognition got involved at any point, "r" and "n" are similar.

Comment: If you zoom into the copy of the Spectator's printed page, you can see that the text was originally "I find beer boring..."

Comment: This sort of answer is not a scholarly addition to ELU, which focuses on standard usages. Just comment (like FF) and CV.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True. In fact I did, then felt guilty that I was giving an "answer as a comment," which I know is a sore point here (though maybe not unanimously), and deleted the comment and converted to an answer. Though I guess now I can't do the opposite now that it's been accepted...

Comment: FF's 'I’m voting to close this question because it's about an OCR transcription error' gets round the problem very easily.